# How to build simple rich textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I build a very simple rich textbox using javascript or jquery to make selected text bold ?

```
< textarea id="editor">< /textarea>
< input type="button" onclick="bold()" value="Bold selected" />
```

Here, the text should be appeared to be really bold but not between < b> and < /b> tag. I mean actually like we are editing in wordpress or other rich textbox.

Comment: Usually a "rich textbox" is a `div` (or `pre`) element with `contenteditable` attribute set to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

The `WYSIWYG` editor plugins don't actually use a `textarea`.They use an editable `div` which makes it possible to show **rich text** .

These links should help you get started:

[HTML contentEditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable)

[WYSIWG Tutorial 1](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1192)

[WYSIWG Tutorial 2](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1193)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make just a selected text inside a `textarea` to be `bold` unless you use some plugins (if exist) or create your own. But instead of inventing the wheel, just use free editors like [**codemirror**](http://codemirror.com//) or [**ckeditor**](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: But I am trying to make such a textbox myself.

Comment: Put some code in jsfiddle and show us your work, if you faced problems put it in SO @user3603684

Comment: @Amir There's no plugin which could make `textarea` to show rich text. [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) can't have HTML, and that's it.

Comment: @Teemu yup exactly you need javascript for that, that's why I suggested to create a plug in or use a free editor, this is a project that the OP is responsible to start and we are ready to help for SO related questions :)